# Join without indexing the entire table

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb-10.4

I have a query that pulls the 3 most recently commented posts on our forum. The issue is is that `COUNT(forum_posts.id) as posts,` is indexing the entire database of 600,000 posts and the query takes forever to complete. I'm left joining the table like this `LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_posts.topic_id = forum_topics.id`. Apparently I will have to use another approach to this. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT    forum_topics.id, 
         forum_topics.title, 
         forum_topics.date_created, 
         forum_topics.updated, 
         forum_topics.last_activity, 
         forum_topics.category_id,
         SUBSTR(forum_topics.content, 1, 70) as content, 
         forum_topics.author_id,
         users.username,
         users.avatar,
         COUNT(forum_posts.id) as posts,
         CASE WHEN forum_topics_seen.user_id = 49 then 1 else 0 end as seen,
         forum_categories.category_order,
         forum_categories.name as cat_name
FROM forum_topics 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = forum_topics.author_id
LEFT JOIN forum_topics_seen ON forum_topics_seen.topic_id = forum_topics.id AND forum_topics_seen.user_id = 49
LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_posts.topic_id = forum_topics.id
LEFT JOIN forum_categories ON forum_categories.id = forum_topics.category_id
GROUP BY forum_topics.id
ORDER BY forum_topics.last_activity DESC LIMIT 3
```

Result from SHOW CREATE TABLE forum_posts

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `updated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102183 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `forum_topics_seen` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `forum_categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `game` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `updated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_activity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_locked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `FK_forum_topics_forum_categories` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INTEGER,
  username VARCHAR (30),
  avatar   VARCHAR (30)
);
```

Mysql version: 10.4.8-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I've wrestled with this and I've come up with a query which, while not perfect, **should** run better than your one!

I have no sample data, but here is the result of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of your query (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=63520875ad441176cc11ddca1c192b97)):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  forum_topics    ALL                 1   100.00  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  users   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db_1663433212.forum_topics.author_id    1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  forum_topics_seen   ref topic_id,user_id    topic_id    4   db_1663433212.forum_topics.id   1   100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  forum_posts ALL                 1   100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
1   SIMPLE  forum_categories    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db_1663433212.forum_topics.category_id  1   100.00
```

and the result of my `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`i is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY ft  ALL                 1   100.00  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db_1663433212.ft.author_id  1   100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY fts ref topic_id,user_id    topic_id    4   db_1663433212.ft.id 1   100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY fc  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db_1663433212.ft.category_id    1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 2   100.00  Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
2   DERIVED forum_posts index       PRIMARY 4       1   100.00  Using index
6 rows
```

If you look at the last line of mine, you will see that I am using the `PRIMARY KEY` of forum_posts, whereas your query does not do so. I would imagine (hope) that this will result in a considerable improvement in performance.

Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED WITH p_cnt AS
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pcnt FROM forum_posts
)
SELECT  
         ft.id, 
         ft.title, 
         ft.date_created, 
         ft.updated, 
         ft.last_activity, 
         ft.category_id,
         SUBSTR(ft.content, 1, 70) as content, 
         ft.author_id,
         u.username,
         u.avatar,
         p.pcnt,
         CASE WHEN fts.user_id = 49 then 1 else 0 end as seen,
         fc.category_order,
         fc.name as cat_name
FROM forum_topics ft 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = ft.author_id  -- author_id needs to be a FOREIGN KEY but I can't get it to work in a fiddle!
LEFT JOIN forum_topics_seen fts ON  fts.topic_id = ft.id 
                                AND fts.user_id = 49
LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON fc.id = ft.category_id 
CROSS JOIN p_cnt p
GROUP BY ft.id
ORDER BY ft.last_activity DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

The most important thing is that I am using a CTE ([`Common Table Expression`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/)) to get the count of `forum_posts` and then I basically use that value as a "constant" in the following query - this considerably simplifies matters. CTEs are very powerful and well worth getting to know!

I am using the explict `CROSS JOIN` syntax in my join of my count to the rest - you could also write this line:

```
    LEFT JOIN forum_categories fc ON fc.id = ft.category_id, p_cnt p
```

known as the `comma syntax`. Personally, I prefer to put it out there in bold and caps - it makes things clearer and is easier to read. Speaking of making things easier to read, note that my query uses table aliases which, IMHO, vastly improves readability - YMMV!

I would be grateful if you could run this SQL and report back here on any performance change (improvement! :-) ).

There were several things about your SQL that I think you should look at.

- As I pointed out already, your original table definitions had lines like this:

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)

The `UNIQUE KEY`id`(`id`)` is redundant, since `PRIMARY KEY`s are, by definition, unique.

- You should **ALWAYS** put `FOREIGN KEY`s on fields which do actually `JOIN` tables - and index is [automatically created](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html) which helps with performance. For example, I added:

  FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) REFERENCES forum_topics (id)

I had difficulty (noted in the table definitions) adding some `FOREIGN KEY` definitions in the fiddle - not sure why this is. Maybe you'll have better luck?

- You should also index fields upon which you are filtering - I added these lines:

  KEY (`topic_id`, `user_id`),   -- added this
  KEY (`user_id`),     -- added this

There can be religious debates about which fields to index and which not - you can have loads of fun during the current lockdown experimenting with various indexes! :-)

- I notice that you had one strange line in your table definition of `forum_topics`. You wrote:

  KEY `FK_forum_topics_forum_categories` (`category_id`)

Now, were you trying to create a `FOREIGN KEY` for the field `category_id` in the table `forum_topics` pointing at the table `forum_categories`? If so, then the syntax goes like this:

```
-- FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES forum_categories (id),  -- couldn't get this to work
```

For some reason, as I mentioned above, I couldn't get a couple of `FOREIGN KEY` defintions to work and I don't have a running MariaDB system to test on - maybe you'll have better luck on a live system?

I hope this has been helpful - if you have other issues, don't hesitate to get back to me!

========================== Tables ==================================

### users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `username` VARCHAR (30),
  `avatar`   VARCHAR (30)
);
```

### forum_posts:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `updated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  -- FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES users (id) -- can't get this to work!
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102183 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### forum_categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `game` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  -- UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### forum_topics:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `updated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_activity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_locked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES forum_categories (id),  -- couldn't get this to work
  KEY `FK_forum_topics_forum_categories` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### forum_topics_seen:

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `author_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `updated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_activity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_locked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES forum_categories (id),  -- couldn't get this to work
  KEY `FK_forum_topics_forum_categories` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: original query calculates COUNT(forum_posts.id) as posts GROUP BY forum_topics.id - the number of posts in each topic. It's not constant, this value may be different for each topic.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_forum_posts_topic_id ON forum_posts(topic_id);
CREATE INDEX ix_forum_topics_last_activity ON forum_topics(last_activity);
CREATE INDEX ix_forum_topics_seen_topic_id_user_id  ON forum_topics_seen(topic_id, user_id);
```

After that you could use this simple query:

```
WITH CTE_topics AS (SELECT id FROM forum_topics ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT 3)
SELECT    forum_topics.id, 
         forum_topics.title, 
         forum_topics.date_created, 
         forum_topics.updated, 
         forum_topics.last_activity, 
         forum_topics.category_id,
         SUBSTR(forum_topics.content, 1, 70) as content, 
         forum_topics.author_id,
         users.username,
         users.avatar,
         (SELECT COUNT(forum_posts.id) FROM forum_posts WHERE  forum_posts.topic_id = forum_topics.id) as posts,
         CASE WHEN forum_topics_seen.user_id = 49 then 1 else 0 end as seen,
         forum_categories.category_order,
         forum_categories.name as cat_name
FROM forum_topics 
INNER JOIN CTE_topics ON forum_topics.id = CTE_topics.id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = forum_topics.author_id
LEFT JOIN forum_topics_seen ON forum_topics_seen.topic_id = forum_topics.id AND forum_topics_seen.user_id = 49
LEFT JOIN forum_categories ON forum_categories.id = forum_topics.category_id;
```

Comment: Nice one! Yours is the solution towards which I was struggling! I **knew** I could take the `LIMIT 3` out of the main query. I'd be very interested to hear from the OP what the performance of your solution is!

Answer (score 1):

Turn the query inside-out.  First, let's check the viability of such.  Will this give you the correct 3 ids?

```
SELECT  ft.id
    FROM  forum_topics AS ft
    ORDER BY  ft.last_activity DESC
    LIMIT  3
```

If so, then build the rest of the query *starting* with that:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( the-above-query )
    JOIN forum_topics AS ft2 ON ft2.id = ft.id  -- to get other ft2 columns
    JOIN/LEFT-JOIN the other tables
    ORDER BY  ft.last_activity DESC
```

The `GROUP BY` probably is not needed.  This is a speedup.

The other tables will need to look at only 3 rows each, instead of lots.  Hence, it may be much faster.

I don't understand the purpose of users.  If it is part of the filtering, then the inside ("derived table") query will need to include it:

```
SELECT  ft.id
    FROM  forum_topics AS ft
    INNER JOIN  users AS u  ON u.id = ft.author_id
    ORDER BY  ft.last_activity DESC
    LIMIT  3
```

and you would need to re-join to it to get `username` and `avatar`

Other issues...

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` index; don't redundantly say `UNIQUE(id)`.

You have no indexes other than `id`; that is terrible.  These are probably useful:

```
forum_topics:  (last_activity, id)   -- "covering" for the first use
forum_posts:  (topic_id, id)            -- "covering"
forum_topics_seen:  (user_id, topic_id)  -- in either order
```

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the performance of my "derived table" approach to Nikita's "CTE" approach.  @fahreit -- Will you do such?  (In doing so, you will learn two un-obvious approaches to writing queries.)